# Problem adding column to WC Subscription

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, columns

I am having trouble adding custom column to Woocommerce Subscription.

My codes are as below:

```
add_filter( 'manage_shop_subscription_posts_columns', function ($columns) {
    $columns['my_field'] = __('My Field');

    return $columns;
}, 10);
```

What could be wrong with my code? I fail to understand why it is not working.

Comment: Is hard to say what is wrong with your code because WooCommerce has  no subscription functionality , so you must use a 3th party plugin.  I think you will get the best support from the plugin developer. Do you asked him or her?

Comment: @user141080 It's a known addon sold by Woocommerce: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/

Comment: "WooCommerce Subscriptions" is a pay plugin so please ask the  support for help

Comment: @user141080 Hmm alright. I will post my answer here once I have a solution from them.

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: @TomJNowell I disagree. Woocommerce is not a 3rd-party plugin, it is part of WordPress and is owned by the same company, Automattic, Inc.

Comment: Automattic is a 3rd party company, WooCommerce is a 3rd party plugin. I can confirm this as a former employee of Automattic, and Automattic themselves say this on their website. WordPress.com is not WordPress.org, even the code has major differences (I know because I have seen it first hand)

Comment: Here it is spelt out from the wp.org side: https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-vs-wordpress-com/

Comment: Here it is spelt out from the wp.com side: https://wordpress.com/go/business-website-guidance/wordpress-com-vs-wordpress-org/ This stack is for questions about WordPress the open source project. 3rd party plugins are not in our scope. 1st party plugins include gutenberg, the classic editor plugin, the classic widgets plugin, the wp beta test plugin, and other official feature plugins maintained by the open source project. Products of the company Automattic are not 1st party products, and Automattic does not claim them to be. WooCommerce questions are off topic here, and not in scope.

Comment: SE is becoming very confusing these days. SO mods will reject it because it is WP-related. WPSE mods will reject it because it is third-party. Where would a person with a genuine code-related query for an opensource project go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so since WC Subscriptions is creating it's own array for columns. Any filter priority lesser than their function will simply make your code non-functional. So what I did is I changed priority from 10 to 1000 so that my codes fire after their code.

```
add_filter( 'manage_shop_subscription_posts_columns', function ($columns) {
    $columns['my_field'] = __('My Field');

    return $columns;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this. It helped me. By the way, you can mark your own answer as 'accepted' answer, don't you?

Comment: @Himadri Yes, forgot to do that. :P

Answer (score 2):

We should use `manage_edit-shop_subscription_columns` instead of `manage_shop_subscription_posts_columns`. At the moment, I think the latter is not available.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_subscription_columns', function ( $columns ) {
  $columns['my_field'] = __('My Field');
  return $columns;
}, 10 );
```

It doesn't need to change the priority.

Comment: Without changing the priority the code is not working for me. So I changed the priority and it started working.

Comment: In my circumstances, there is no need to set priority. Maybe it is because of other settings or plugins. Anyway, it is worth trying, if the filter is not working.